# How to arrange items in list from highest to lowest (word occurence using I/O)?

Tags: java

I have a working word occurrence program that took me a while to code (still new at Java) and I was wondering if I could get a little assistance. Here is my code that I have so far:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TestWordOccurenceProgram {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String thisLine = null;
    try {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("myTextDocument.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        //List<String> wordList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
        // make ArrayList of integers
        List<Integer> counts = new ArrayList<>();

        String word = "";

        while ((thisLine = br.readLine()) != null ) {
            word = word.concat(thisLine);
            word = word.concat(" ");
        }

        String[] wordList = word.split("\\s");


        for (int i = 0; i < wordList.length; i++) {
            String temp = wordList[i];
            if(words.contains(temp)) {
                int x = words.indexOf(temp);
                int value = counts.get(x);
                value++;
                counts.set(x, value);
            }
            else {
                words.add(temp);
                counts.add(1);
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(words.get(i) + ": " + counts.get(i));

        }

        br.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);

    } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is what "myTextDocument.txt" has:

```
i am a rabbit
a happy rabbit am
yay i am a rabbit
a rabbit i am yay
```

Here is my output:

```
i: 3
am: 4
a: 4
rabbit: 4
happy: 1
yay: 2
```

Does anyone know if I could arrange these items from the highest number of word occurrences to the lowest number of word occurrences? Any help would be great!

Comment: Have you already learned how to sort arrays?

Comment: @PM77-1 How does that help.  He has two arrays which need to be kept in sync

Comment: Kind of. I made a quick sort method. Can you check to see if this is right or not?

 `public static void sort(int[] numb, int count) {
  for (int j = 0; j < count; j++) {
   int temp;
   for (int k = 0; k < count - 1; k++) {
    if (numb[k] > numb[k + 1]) {
     temp = numb[k + 1];
     numb[k + 1] = numb[k];
     numb[k] = temp;
    }
   }
  }
 }`

Comment: My first idea, is to create a class that represents one of the words, with a instance variable for the number of occurrences. Then, I would have that class implement the Comparable interface so that the Collections.sort() method could be used easily on an ArrayList of that class

Comment: Have alook at this link http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/util/set/java-sorted-set-example/

Comment: @ScaryWombat - for example, use bubble-sort and swap the same elements in the 2nd array instead.

Comment: @PM77-1 Would you really do it that way?

Comment: @ScaryWombat - If I'm limited to arrays of primitives - yes.

Comment: @ScaryWombat, I clicked on the link and tried to explain to myself how the code works... but I just don't get it. :/

Comment: see @chris answer below

Answer (score 4):

You can use Map instead of List. and use compare method to sort map via its value. 
refer this code :

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class PQ {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String thisLine = null;
    try {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("D:\\test.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        HashMap<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
        ValueComparator comparator =  new ValueComparator(map);
        TreeMap<String, Integer> treemap = new TreeMap<String, Integer>(comparator);

        while((thisLine = br.readLine()) != null){
            String[] str = thisLine.split("\\s+");
            for(String s:str){
                if(map.containsKey(s)){
                    Integer i = map.get(s);
                    i++;
                    map.put(s,i);
                }else{
                    map.put(s, 1);
                }
            }
        }
        treemap.putAll(map);
        System.out.println(treemap);
        br.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);

    } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}

class ValueComparator implements Comparator<String>{

    Map<String, Integer> base;
    public ValueComparator(Map<String, Integer> base) {
        this.base = base;
    }

    public int compare(String a, String b) {
        if (base.get(a) >= base.get(b)) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Rather than using two separate lists (one with words, one with counts), why not create a `WordAndCount` object that has something like `getWord` and `getCount` methods? This `WordAndCount` class can implement `Comparable`, where you do comparisons based on count.  Then, you can store a single `List<WordAndCount>`, and just sort the single list using `Collections.sort`.

Roughly, the outline could look like this:

```
public class WordAndCount implements Comparable<WordAndCount> {
    private String word;
    private int count;
    public WordAndCount(String word) {...}
    public void incrementCount() {...}
    public int compareTo(WordAndCount other) {...}
}
```

Wrapping up the combination into a single class makes this much easier to solve, as it provides the easy link between word and its count.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using Collections in Java for this, but instead you can use temp variables.

So the idea is to sort by counts. Pseudo-code before outputting:

```
int tempCount;
String tempWord;

for (int i = 1; i < counts.size(); i++) {

if (counts.get(i) < counts.get(i-1)) {

tempCount = counts.get(i-1);
tempWord = words.get(i-1);

counts.set(i-1, i);
counts.set(i, tempCount);

words.set(i-1, i);
words.set(i, tempWord);
}
```

You'd need an extra loop around that to correctly order them but hopefully gives you the right idea.